# Running java program where config files are in a different directory

Tags: java, spring, classpath, config

I am running a java program , my program is in a jar file (executable jar that I have created) lets name it as Test.jar
My program requires some property which are present in config.properties file , I have not included in the jar but kept them in a directory named conf
Now I need to add these config files to classpath so that program can have these properties while running.

But the problem is that the property file is not found during my program execution its throwing file not found exception. I am using spring 5 and reading the configuration using annotation @PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties","classpath:application.properties"})
so ideally if I put the configuration in classpath it should read.

n.b- I have no issues in running the program using eclipse where my property files are in resource dir

I am running the program from command line as - 
java -cp "Test.jar;conf*" com.test.TestMain

I am getting file not found exception

My directory structure is TestCode directory and inside I have conf dir and Test.jar file and I am running from TestCode directory

Also my maven build structure look like below , not sure if something to do with maven

```
<build>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<excludes>
<exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
<exclude>**/log4j2.xml</exclude>
</excludes>
<filtering>false</filtering>
</resource>
</resources>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<archive>
<manifest>
<mainClass>com.test.TestMain</mainClass>
</manifest>
</archive>
<descriptorRefs>
<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>copy-resources</id>
<phase>install</phase>
<goals>
<goal>copy-resources</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
</resource>
</resources>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins> 
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

exception I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class 
[com.test.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
at com.test.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:452)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
```

Comment: Within `@PropertySource`, give the location of the properties file as `file:/path/to/config.properties`

Comment: Thanks Madhu , but in this case I am fixing the path of the property file, my entire program is in TestCode directory consisting of conf dir with property file and the jar file containing the main class and otheres , I want to place that directory in any machine and run it from there, for this I want to use the property file from classpath.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to place the entire TestCode directory in any machine and run the jar from there? Then you need to have a configurable @PropertySource where you can pass the location of the conf file as command line arg while starting the app with `java -jar`

Comment: Have it as `@PropertySource(value = "${file.path}")` and pass the `file.path` arg as `-Dfile.path=file:/path/to/config.properties`

Comment: Thanks Madhu, it worked but any idea what was the problem with the -cp option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this being run in Windows or Linux? Because separator for -cp is semicolon for Windows and Colon for Unix.
Have you tried java -Dspring.config.location=/conf/ -jar Test.jar ? This probably is more straightforward for what you explain is your need.

Comment: I am running the program in windows

Comment: @Avishek Did you try java -Dspring.config.location=/conf/ -jar Test.jar  as I mentioned above?